# Is there any way to get values corresponding to a column in a table upon selecting the table heading name?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, html-table

I have a table using json data from an API. I want to select a table heading and its corresponding values. The table heading and values may change for different data sets.

I am using Angular Material for creating the table.

Here is the template code for creating the table-

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of displayedColumns; let colIndex = 
     index" matColumnDef="{{ disCol }}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
          <mat-checkbox
            #checkbox
            (change)="onClickSelect(checkbox)"
            value={{disCol}}
            labelPosition="before"
            >{{ disCol }}
          </mat-checkbox>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            {{ element[disCol] }}
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true">
    </tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns">
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is the component ts file where the `dataSource` and `displayedColumns` values are coming from an service.

```js
showTableData() {
  this.tableLoading=true
  this.showTab= !this.showTab;
  this.displayedColumns= this.fileService.objectKey ;
  this.dataSource = this.fileService.totalObject ;
  this.tableLoading=false;
}
onClickSelect(event){
  console.log('Corresponding Column values',event.value)
}
```

SO here the actual output would be - After getting the table I will be having the option to select any particular column and get corresponding values.And I don't want to select multiple columns.

Thanks in advance for your time here.

Comment: I just have edited this post. Now I am able to get the column value name but I want to only restrict to one selection. How to do that?